# How to add data in two tables and delete data at the same time using one button?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010, crud, ms-access-2007

"i have problem in my Students Registration form, i want to insert my students information in my different database.

table for students information

and table for courses ICT, ABM & HE

I also want to insert, update, delete, both of the data inserted in this two different databases, with only one button in one Form in vb.net"

```
connect()



if txtStudID = "" and txtF.text = "" and txtM.text = "" and txtS.text = "" then



    messagebox.show("Please Complete the Data")



else



    comm.Connection =conn



    comm.Commandtext = "INSERT into MyDatabase values ('" & txtStudID.text & "', '" & txtF.text & "', '" & txtM.text & "', '" & txtS.text & "', '" & dtpDOB.text & "', '" & cboGender.text & "', '" & txtAge.text & "', '" & cboProg.text & "', '" & cboYr.text & "', '" & Source.text & "', '" & txtPhone.text & "', '" & txtEmail.text & "', '" & txtAddress.text & "', '" & RD.text & "')"



    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()



    populate()



    Myclear()



end if 







'to the second table







if cboProg.Text = ICT then



    comm.Connection =conn



    comm.Commandtext = "INSERT into ICT values ('" & txtStudID.text & "', '" & txtF.text & "', '" & txtM.text & "', '" & txtS.text & "', '" & dtpDOB.text & "', '" & cboGender.text & "', '" & txtAge.text & "', '" & cboProg.text & "', '" & cboYr.text & "', '" & Source.text & "', '" & txtPhone.text & "', '" & txtEmail.text & "', '" & txtAddress.text & "', '" & RD.text & "')"



    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()



    messagebox.show("Successfully Registered as an ICT STUDENT!")



elseif cboProg.Text = ABM then



    comm.Connection =conn



    comm.Commandtext = "INSERT into ABM values ('" & txtStudID.text & "', '" & txtF.text & "', '" & txtM.text & "', '" & txtS.text & "', '" & dtpDOB.text & "', '" & cboGender.text & "', '" & txtAge.text & "', '" & cboProg.text & "', '" & cboYr.text & "', '" & Source.text & "', '" & txtPhone.text & "', '" & txtEmail.text & "', '" & txtAddress.text & "', '" & RD.text & "')"



    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()



    messagebox.show("Successfully Registered as an ABM STUDENT!")
elseif cboProg.Text = HE then
    comm.Connection =conn
    comm.Commandtext = "INSERT into HE values ('" & txtStudID.text & "', '" & txtF.text & "', '" & txtM.text & "', '" & txtS.text & "', '" & dtpDOB.text & "', '" & cboGender.text & "', '" & txtAge.text & "', '" & cboProg.text & "', '" & cboYr.text & "', '" & Source.text & "', '" & txtPhone.text & "', '" & txtEmail.text & "', '" & txtAddress.text & "', '" & RD.text & "')"



    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()



    messagebox.show("Successfully Registered as an HE STUDENT!")



    END IF
```

Comment: _i have problem_.  You really need to explain that problem.  What exactly isn't working for you giving us details of any exceptions encountered or a clear explanation of how this doesn't meet requirements.  Few things of a quick eye balling of the code you've given us.  1)  Learn how to parametrise sql commands.  Heaps of examples around, many on this site. 2) Read up on the Using clause and how it applies to classes that implement IDisposable.  While neither of these suggestions might fix the issue, it will be far more robust code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.